# How to SaveAs a Worksheet to new Workbook in specific folder

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Once I am complete with my reporting in Excel, I'd like to SaveAs a new Sheet into a new workbook into the same location as the PDF created (a subfolder).
I will email the Excel file to a client and they can edit and return so the client's data doesn't have to be transposed and the form will look just like the PDF essentially.

Also, the output file name will need to be the same as the existing output PDF file (cell data supplies this) so that the file is not lost due to renaming issues, and will match the transmittal.

The code I have creates subfolders, and organizes everything in them with a resulted PDF, however I cannot get an Excel file too that is text only (the one method I found copies the macro buttons, formulas linking to the original file, etc.).
I want the formatting, not the cell formulas, just the cell text.

```vb
Sub SCL_SaveAndFile()

    Dim myDir As String, mySht As String, mySubDir As String, mySubSub As String, mySubName As String, mySubName1 As String
    
    'Example of current Folder Structure
    'C:\RFP Documents\[RFP NUMBER]\[CLIENT NAME]\[DOCUMENT TITLE]\Document.pdf

    'Would also like this, of just the active sheet, with just text no formulas copied
    'C:\RFP Documents\[RFP NUMBER]\[CLIENT NAME]\[DOCUMENT TITLE]\Document.xslx

    myDir = "C:\RFP Documents\" 'root destination
    mySubDir = ActiveSheet.Range("R3").Value 'rfp number
    mySubSub = ActiveSheet.Range("R2").Value 'client name
    mySubName = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value 'document title
    mySubName1 = "RFP PACKAGE" 'sub folder where documents are stored to be emailed to client
    mySht = ActiveSheet.Range("R1").Value 'document no or filename
    
    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir myDir
    MkDir myDir & "\" & mySubDir
    MkDir myDir & "\" & mySubDir & "\" & mySubSub & "\" & mySubName1
    MkDir myDir & "\" & mySubDir & "\" & mySubSub & "\" & mySubName1 & "\" & mySubName
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        filename:=myDir & "\" & mySubDir & "\" & mySubSub & "\" & "\" & mySubName1 & "\" & mySubName & "\" & mySht, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this Below you Code:**

- Copy the Activesheet
- Paste Special all the Formats and Values
- Save the Newly Created workbook at the same Destination

---

```
Dim nwb As Workbook, wb As Workbook, wks As Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set wks = ActiveSheet
wks.Copy
Set nwb = ActiveWorkbook
With nwb.Worksheets(1)
.UsedRange.Copy
.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With

nwb.SaveAs fileName:=myDir & "\" & mySubDir & "\" & mySubSub & "\" & "\" & mySubName1 & "\" & mySubName & "\" & mySht & ".xlsx"
nwb.Close
```

---

**Full Code**

```
Sub SCL_SaveAndFile()

    Dim myDir As String, mySht As String, mySubDir As String, mySubSub As String, mySubName As String, mySubName1 As String
    Dim nwb As Workbook, wb As Workbook, wks As Worksheet
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    myDir = "C:\RFP Documents\" 'root destination
    mySubDir = ActiveSheet.Range("R3").Value 'rfp number
    mySubSub = ActiveSheet.Range("R2").Value 'client name
    mySubName = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value 'document title
    mySubName1 = "RFP PACKAGE" 'sub folder where documents are stored to be emailed to client
    mySht = ActiveSheet.Range("R1").Value 'document no or filename

    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir myDir
    MkDir myDir & "\" & mySubDir
    MkDir myDir & "\" & mySubDir & "\" & mySubSub & "\" & mySubName1
    MkDir myDir & "\" & mySubDir & "\" & mySubSub & "\" & mySubName1 & "\" & mySubName
    On Error GoTo 0

    wks.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        fileName:=myDir & "\" & mySubDir & "\" & mySubSub & "\" & "\" & mySubName1 & "\" & mySubName & "\" & mySht, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

    wks.Copy

    Set nwb = ActiveWorkbook
    With nwb.Worksheets(1)
    .UsedRange.Copy
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With

    nwb.SaveAs fileName:=myDir & "\" & mySubDir & "\" & mySubSub & "\" & "\" & mySubName1 & "\" & mySubName & "\" & mySht & ".xlsx"
    nwb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems to error out in two manners. One being that the existing code calls to "Active Sheet" for the filename data but since the code calls it to the new sheet, the current Active Sheet is no longer valid. Secondly, The origin Sheet has merged cells, and the result sheet essentially does not yet, so its throwing  errors and looking corrupt there too. Ive tried tinkering with what you provided, and cannot get it. Im sorry I didnt mention this sooner.